# display name from json array?

Tags: angularjs, json

what I want is first I want to display name from array temples by loop.
next thing is I want to display array subdieties.here in  $scope.result we will get all the json data.and in $scope.result.data.root we will get diety's information

app.js

```
 $scope.templeEn = 'js/templeEnglish.js';

             $scope.loadtempleEn= function (file) {
                $http.get(file)
                .then(function (result) {
                    $scope.result=result;
                     console.log( $scope.result);
                    console.log($scope.result.data.root);



                })
             }


        $scope.loadtempleEn($scope.templeEn);
```

Comment: I am not sure what the question actually is. Can you clarify, is the result not being set correctly? Are you wondering how to repeat over this in the view?

Comment: I want to loop array temples first and next I want to loop array "subdieties thats all @AdamCooper86

Answer (score 1):

As my understanding you want to know how to loop via div's to show name  and subdieties.

You can do like this..

```
<div ng-repeat='result in results.root'>
    <div ng-repeat='temple in result.temples'>
        Temples Name {{temple.name}} 
        <div ng-repeat='sub in temple.subdieties'>
            {{sub}}
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: based on the question and comments, this would be the correct way to display the information in angular. Generally speaking, unless you need to transform the data you are working with, it is best to use directives like ng-repeat to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module("stack", [])
    .controller("move", function($scope) {
        // this.apps = features;
        $scope.result = {
            "root": [{
                "diety": "Krishna",
                "image": "krishna.png",
                "info": "Information regarding Krishna",
                "details": "Details of Krishna",
                "rounds": "4 Times",
                "temples": [{
                    "name": "Guruvayoor",
                    "address": "Guruvayoor, Thrissur",
                    "phone": "3333444",
                    "subdieties": ["Ganapati", "Sasthaavu", "Devi"]
                }, {
                    "name": "Thruvaoor",
                    "address": "Thuravoor, Alapuzha",
                    "phone": "31249652",
                    "subdieties": ["Nagarajavu", "Ganapati", "Sasthaavu", "Devi"]
                }, {
                    "name": "Ambalapuzha",
                    "address": "Ambalapuzha, Alapuzha",
                    "phone": "2255321",
                    "subdieties": ["Ganapati"]
                }]
            }, {
                "diety": "Paramasivan",
                "image": "siva.png",
                "info": "Information regarding Paramasivan",
                "details": "Details of Paramasivan",
                "rounds": "3 Times",
                "temples": [{
                    "name": "Mammiyoor",
                    "address": "Mammiyoor, Thrissur",
                    "phone": "2222444",
                    "subdieties": ["Mahavishnu", "Ganapati", "Subramanian", "Sasthaavu", "Devi"]
                }, {
                    "name": "Velorvattom",
                    "address": "Cherthala, Alapuzha",
                    "phone": "21299652",
                    "subdieties": ["Nagarajavu", "Ganapati", "Sasthaavu", "Devi", "Mahavishnu", "Yakshi", "Brahmarakshasu"]
                }]
            }]
        }
        $scope.array = [];
        $scope.result.root.forEach(function(each) {
            console.log("each ", each.temples);
            each.temples.forEach(function(e) {
                // console.log("e ", e);
                $scope.array.push({ "name": e.name, "subdieties": e.subdieties });
            })

        })
        console.log("array ", $scope.array);
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="stack">

<head>
    <title>stack</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- // <script type="text/javascript" src="loadingoverlay.js"></script> -->
    <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- // <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="move">
    <div ng-repeat="val in array">
        <p style="background-color:red">{{val.name}}</p>
        <div ng-repeat="value in val.subdieties">
            <p>{{value}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Do you need this? @Sherin

Comment: what do you want to display? is the snippet code working properly?

Comment: got the error like cannot read the property of foreach undefined @batman

Comment: how is this possible? I didn't get any error like this. did you run the snippet?

Comment: I think for your code you have to write $scope.result.data.root.forEach . Please let me know if it is working or not?

Answer (score 0):

See jsfiddle i prepared here

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/7934)

`angular.forEach(result.root, function(value) {
    angular.forEach(value.temples, function(temple) {
      $scope.temples.push(temple);
      angular.forEach(temple.subdieties, function(subdiety) {
        $scope.subdieties.push(subdiety);
      });
    });
  });`

Comment: got an error like ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: dont change the json structure please do it on the same json as I displayed pradeep1991singh

Comment: Please check jsfiddle. You can replace `var data` with the actual data you are getting from JSON file and then you can iterate(loop) data as i did.

Comment: will you please explain one more times please @pradeep1991singh

Comment: Yeah, sure. Replace
`              $scope.result=result;
                 console.log( $scope.result);
                console.log($scope.result.data.root);`

with code i provided.

It will look something like this

`$scope.loadtempleEn= function (file) {
            $http.get(file)
            .then(function (result) {
angular.forEach(result.root, function(value) {
    angular.forEach(value.temples, function(temple) {
      $scope.temples.push(temple);
      angular.forEach(temple.subdieties, function(subdiety) {
        $scope.subdieties.push(subdiety);
      });
    });
  });
})
}`